# Fixing the amount of variable in Gurobi - Python as a parameter for another model

Tags: python, gurobi

I have solved a very simple mathematical model ( 2 variables) using Gurobi in Python and now I want to fix the amount of the variable in another model and solve it, for example, consider the variable $x_2$ is solved and it is equal to $2$, and now I want to add it to another mathematical programming as an input (parameter) the problem is, Gurobi expects the $x_2$ to be a variable, not a parameter wich finally gives the error "Variable not in model", I would appreciate it if anyone can help me with this issue.

Comment: What I can suggest is to define $x_2$ in the second model as a parameter, rather than a variable. If you post the code we can see how you are doing this and help you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_2^1$ be the variable in the first model, and $x_2^2$ be the corresponding variable in the second model. Also, let $\hat{x}_2^1$ be the optimal value of $x_2^1$, after solving the first model.

So if you want to add the optimal value of $x_2^1$ in the second model, use the constraint
$$
x_2^2 = \hat{x}_2^1
$$

Comment: Thanks for answering, the point is, it actually expects x22 being implemented as something in the model, if I implement it as a variable, it gives an error of not being a PSD ( Positive Semi Definite ), because the structure is somehow Nonlinear, so now I want to add it as a parameter in the model, and I don't know-how.